# How to position a picture flyout

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

So i have this problem. I want to center my flyout but here is the catch. I do not know what the size of the picture will be since it is a picture uploaded by a user. I also don't what the picture disappearing if i make the screen smaller. I tried to set position to be relative but then it pushes my images / texts behind the flyout down.

```
<div id="imageFlyout<?=$step['order']+1?>" class="popUpWrapper" style="display:none;position:absolute;top:100px;left:<script type="text/JavaScript">
            int w = screen.width;
            <?php $tempSize=getimagesize("guidebook_images/".$step['attachment']); if($tempSize[0] > 935){?>w/2<?php }else{?>w-<?php echo($tempSize[0]/2);}?></script>px;">
```

Comment: You need to provide a sample of your code or a live url that has the issue you're describing present.

Answer (score 0):

Centering in HTML is an easy two step process:

**Give the parent:**

```
text-align:center;
```

**Give the element:**

```
margin:auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uriahjamesgd_73/kNFGj/22/

I used the CSS values VW (viewer width) & VH (viewer height) to specify that the flyout be a percentage of whatever the viewport is at a given instance. Hopefully this allows resizing of the viewport in mobile devices.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="product">
    <span class="flyOut"></span>
  </div>
</div>​

/* CSS */
body { margin: 50px; }
.wrap { position: relative; }
.product { background-color: #555; position: relative; width: 100px; height: 75px; }
span.flyOut { display: none; background-color: #ddd; position: absolute; width: 50vw; height: 37.5vh; left: 100%; }
.product:hover > span.flyOut { display: inline-block; }
```

​